# UK citizen living in UK, contractor for US company. ESTA Requirements?

Tags: usa, esta, uk-citizens, us-visa-waiver-program

- I'm a UK citizen who lives permanently in the UK
- I work as a self-employed contractor/consultant for a US company. I work for them primarily remotely from the UK, and the company sends my payments directly to me in the UK. The company has no intermediary or presence in the UK
- They plan to have me travel to the US every few months for face-to-face meetings and discussions with some team members and higher-ups. For these trips, I pay for them myself as a self-employment expense.

My question is whether an ESTA is appropriate here, or some other sort of visa.

Comment: Do you operate as a sole proprietor or have you set up some sort of legal entity?  Do your US clients pay you hourly or on some other basis?  The potentially tricky question here is "income from a US source."

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have any sort of legal entity, I am working as a sole proprietor/sole trader, as opposed to forming a limited company. The US clients pay daily rates

Comment: @phoog the income is from a US source but this is when I'm working remotely from the UK. While in the US, there will be no income since these are just meetings - I will not be billing them for the time spent in the US.

Comment: "I will not be billing them for the time spent in the US." - that might be hard to prove to CBP or at the consulate when applying for a visa, since you've been billing them for year(s). Effectively (in my mind), you're traveling for personal reasons and "meeting some friends from work for a 'social activity' after work" if you're not billing for your time in these meetings.

Comment: @Freeman what about if I changed my working arrangement and began working through an umbrella company in the UK? So I'd be an employee of the UK umbrella company and they'd contract me out to the US company. Just asking, because it seems ESTA is not for situations where the foreign contractor's income is from a US source. The whole thing is confusing, I feel this can't be the first time a foreign contractor paid by a US company has wanted to travel there for a meeting.

Comment: I am _far_ from expert! However, I think the whole, "I'm going to meet employees of the company I contract to, but won't be billing them for the time we're meeting" thing might raise suspicions should anyone ask. I honestly have no idea what the visa/tax implications are one way of the other, it just _sounds_ (to me) like you're trying to avoid something, even if you aren't. You'll have to wait for someone else to chime in on this one, though.